# Column exceeds row's width when text content is too long

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I have a row that contains 3 columns: The first and last columns are set to the `size: auto` property, and the second columns takes the rest of the available space:

```html
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row nowrap justify-content-center align-items-center>
        <ion-col size="auto">
            <p>I</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="long-text">
            <p>A text that makes this column exceeds the width of the row</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="auto">
            <p>III</p>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Then, to cut the long text, I used this scss code:

```css
ion-grid {
    ion-row {
        ion-col {
            &.long-text {
                p { 
                    white-space: nowrap;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    text-overflow: ellipsis;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, the column containing the long text stretches as long as the width of the text and exceeds its parent row's width

I am looking for a way to show the three dots at the end of the text when it's taking too much space, while keeping at the same time all the columns inside the row.

Comment: You need to restrict the width of the parent of `p`

Comment: I think I can definitely help you figure this out, if you firstly create a fiddle, and secondly show us more code about your parent elements and what position type they hold...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was solved by passing directly the text to the `ion-col` without wrapping it in another element:

```html
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row nowrap justify-content-center align-items-center>
        <ion-col size="auto">
            <p>I</p>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="long-text">
            A text that makes this column exceeds the width of the row
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="auto">
            <p>III</p>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

```css
ion-grid {
    ion-row {
        ion-col {
            &.long-text {
                white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So basically all the columns can vary in size based on there content right?

You need to do `size="auto"` or `col-auto` for all the columns and the `ion-col` with long text need to have fixed width in order for ellipsis to work.

For example, see this stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-yashpatelyk-grid

Comment: This solution works as long as the `ion-col` containing the long text has a fixed width as you mentioned in your answer. In my case this column has a flexible width that changes with the `ion-row` responsive width.